# Почему возникает ошибка route is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js

Пытаюсь осилить node.js но вываливается ошибка вот код 
index.js

```
var server = require("./server");
var router = require("./router");
server.start(router.route);
```

server.js

```
var http = require("http");
var url = require("url");
function start(route) {
  function onRequest(request, response) {
    var pathname = url.parse(request.url).pathname;
    console.log("Request for " + pathname + " received.");
    route(pathname);
    response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
    response.write("Hello World");
    response.end();
  }
  http.createServer(onRequest).listen(8888);
  console.log("Server has started.");
}
exports.start = start;
```

router.js

```
function route(pathname) {
  console.log("About to route a request for " + pathname);
}
exports.route = route;
```

что значит эта ошибка я знаю. Но почему она возникает не понимаю. Объясните а? Вот полный текст ошибки

```
Request for / received.
C:\OpenServer\domains\mayapp\server.js:6
    route(pathname);
    ^

ReferenceError: route is not defined
    at Server.onRequest (C:\OpenServer\domains\mayapp\server.js:6:5)
    at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
    at Server.emit (events.js:172:7)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnIncoming [as onIncoming] (_http_server.js:533:12)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete (_http_common.js:103:23)
```

Comment: Вынесите функцию с функции

Comment: @АндрейШпилевой вы имеете ввиду что я в функцию передаю функцию ?

Comment: приведённый вами код завёлся благополучно у меня,  [вот](http://imgur.com/a/agL7l).

Comment: @AlexanderIgorevich я не отрицаю того что он  благополучно заводится где либо я не понимаю почему у меня не заводится.

Comment: Судя по номерам линий в стэке, код в ответе и твоём компьютере отличаются.

Comment: @elmigranto я просто на сайте лишние пробелы убрал это важно ?

Comment: У меня также завелось - Win7/Node5.8. Попробуйте `console.log(route)` после `console.log("Request for "...` в `server.js` и аналогично в index.js распечатать `router.route` Походу какая то проблема с передачей переменной.